# how to fetch the data according to particular month & year in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, count, fetch

Ok, i have a database in which i have all my users registered with their `datetime` which stores in my MYSQL datetime field as `2012-03-31 12:13:42` now i want to fetch `COUNT` of users according to `year` and `month`.

As i want to present a chart data for that purpose, i want total customers added in `January`, in `feb`, `march` and so on.... in particular year.

i.e it has to be `year specific` that in `2010` `Jan` lets say **52 Customers** in `2010` `Feb` lets say **72 Customers**.

**Note**: The query i want to execute is using PHP and Mysql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the MySQL date functions

```
SELECT YEAR(date_field) as stat_year,
       MONTH(date_field) as stat_month,
       COUNT(*) as stat_count
FROM `table`
GROUP BY stat_year,stat_month
```

If you only want the results for a specific year/month, you can add conditions to the WHERE clause (and remove the GROUP BY) like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as stat_count
FROM `table`
WHERE YEAR(date_field) = 2012
  AND MONTH(date_field) = 3
```

Comment: what is date_field?? I have my mysql field as `datetile` so it stores value like `2012-03-31 12:13:42`....

Comment: It's the name he used to refer to the field which stores the date. You didn't provide it so he used that as a placeholder. Just replace `date_field` with whatever name you've given that field.

Answer (score 2):

There are different SQL that will do the trick, here is one ...

```
SELECT COUNT(dt), DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%b') AS df FROM foo GROUP BY df;
```

where foo is your table name, and dt is the datetime column.  Note that this will apply the function DATE_FORMAT on each row.  Also, you can change the format as desired, e.g. use %m for numeric month, %M for full month name, etc.  Add in where clause to filter as needed.  The following SQL is almost the same ...

```
SELECT COUNT(dt), YEAR(dt) AS y, MONTH(dt) AS m FROM foo GROUP BY y, m;
```

Comment: What is `df` here? is it a typo..?

Comment: It is the alias name I used for the select field DATE_FORMAT(dt, '%Y-%b').  Note that you can alias select output field names, e.g. SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, ...